# What is the source of the Manuals of Golems, and can they be replicated?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting

The book disappears after successfully crafting a golem using it, and the entry in the DMG gives no details as to where the book came from, nor how many are in existence. Can one be created by arcane engineers/scribes? Is there a finite amount of them?

Would the only way to create two golems be to seek out/happen across two unrelated tomes?

Comment: [Related] [Who actually makes the Magic Books that boost stats?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13888)

Answer (score 9):

By strict RAW, the Manual of Golems is the only published method for creating a golem, and you would indeed have to find two unrelated (or possibly related) Manuals in order to make two golems.

*However...* it is **not** RAW that the Manual of Golems has to be the only method for creating a golem. While no other published source exists, it falls totally within a DM's purview to say that there are other methods out there. The same goes for a bunch of other published monsters which are "created with magic" but have no corresponding spells or magic items dictating what that magic is. It's similar to how there's no spell allowing a wizard to become a lich, or no "mishap" rule that says how or why a wizard might turn themselves into a nothic.

Editorially, I'd say that the frequency with which golems show up in games probably is a good indicator that there should be some other means to create one, since they certainly appear to be a good deal more common than a "very rare" magic item.